# GeoPosition and jQuery form

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to use Geoposition API to append to a form the user coordinates, but i cannot understand how to wait for the position to be acquired before sending the form.

I have this form
 EDIT

I'm now trying to submit the form in success callback... no way...

```
 <form id="coordForm" method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" />
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name>
//other input

<button id="sumbit">Submit</button>
                            </form>
<div id="location-lat-long"></div>
```

Then, i was trying to get the position with jQuery but it submit the form without waiting for the coordinates

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#location-lat-long").html("Finding location. Please wait...");
        // check if browser supports the geolocation api
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

        } else {
            $("#location-lat-long").val('Your browser doesn\'t support the geolocation api.');
        }


    });



function errorCallback() {}

function success(position){
    $("#location-lat-long").html("");
    $("#latitude").html(position.coords.latitude);
    $("#longitude").html(position.coords.longitude);
    $('#coordForm').submit();

}


});
```

At the end, the form is not submitted...

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question just to help anyone, because i spent hours...

NEVER NEVER and NEVER call your elements **submit** or other sensitive word...